# In Powershell, how do I close the handle after a ZipFile.OpenRead?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm making a Powershell (Version 3.0, .Net framework 4.5) script that updates some files. However, some of them need to be inspected first.

I open a JAR file and get an entry's content with the following code:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.IO.Compression.FileSystem')
$zentry = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($moduleJarPath).Entries | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match '.*pom.xml'}
```

The entry is read using a System.IO.StreamReader, that is closed right after the read, in a finally block.

Further down the script, I'm going to update the JAR file with a newer one, that might have the same name. In that case, the script fails with:

```
Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'E:\path\to\my\artifact.jar' because it is being used by another process.
```

It looks like the lock is held by my own script, which seems logical since I just accessed the JAR. I'd like to close the handle so that my script can overwrite the JAR.

In the IO.Compression.ZipFile [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.compression.zipfile), there are no "close" method.

How can I release the lock?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`ZipArchive`, which is returned by `ZipFile.OpenRead()`, implements `IDisposable` so you would call `Dispose()` e.g.

```
$zipFile = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($moduleJarPath)
$zentry = $zipFile.Entries | Where-Object {$_.FullName -match '.*pom.xml'}
...
$zipFile.Dispose()
```